# Which algorithm for cost prediction?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, business-intelligence

I don’t have any experience in creating statistical models.

My goal is to to predict future costs for specific areas in the field of facility management (for example repair/maintenance).

I have data for different facilities available like size and specific characteristics. Also I have actual costs from the past years.

Is it possible to create a model to predict future cost with the available data?

I would be very thankful for any recommendations what my next steps should be and ideas which method/algorithm could be used to solve the problem (linear regression?). I am trying to find out in which area I have to learn more to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Yes, you can absolutely create a prediction model. The main question will likely be how much data you have, and how to prevent overfitting. A simple linear regression may indeed be what you want - or not, especially since your response is likely not to be below zero. Can you give a little more information, like how many potential predictors you have, and how many past observations? Perhaps edit your post to include a sample of your data?